# How to split apache arrow flight data into chunks in go

Tags: go, apache-arrow, apache-arrow-flight

The arrow flight data is columnar data and I want to implement DoGet function in such a way that it firstly split arrow.record in to specific size of data (let say 4 MB), then send it to the client using stream. How can I do it?